# Basic MVC structure, URL minimization and GET

Tags: php, .htaccess, get

I'm building a simple MVC structure, my intention is to also have simple URLs (without the file and .php extension), basic rules:

- Everything goes through index.php
- **/index.php/1/2** would be a typical URL, 1-loads the controller class (if such controller exists), 2-calls method (if such method exists)

Here is how I'm hiding **index.php** from my URLs on the htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

This allows me to do **/1/2**

To determine my URL in PHP, I do:

```
$url_parts = array_filter(explode("/", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]));
```

This gives me access to all ny URL segments, I load different files depending on $url_parts[0] (controller) and $url_parts[1] (method/function)

I only have one concern now, and that is working with $_GET on my pages, if I access something like:

```
/1/2?foo=bar
```

My $_GET returns:

```
Array ( [/1/2] => )
```

Whereas I'd obviously want it to be:

```
Array ( [foo] => bar )
```

Can my code be salvaged at all? I obviously don't know how $_GET works that well, I was expecting this to work OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the `QSA` (Query String Append) flag, e.g.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Good stuff! This works nicely, only downside is that /1/2 is still on the $_GET, but I guess that's a "downside" of my implementation.